# Reformat date from DD-MM-YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD in Ansible

Tags: string, ansible

Assume I have this string `22-12-2021`.

I want it to be `2021-12-22` with Ansible.

Any idea if there is a way to do so?

Comment: When you want to drive in a nail, you use a hammer, not a rice cooker. Ansible is not a text processing tool. Use `sed` or `awk` for such tasks. Of course, you can write a playbook that uses `sed` or `awk`, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943501/text-processing-in-a-playbook.

Comment: I dont agree.

Just tried this and it worked: CREATION_DATE.split('-')[::-1] | join('-')

Comment: I declare defeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options of how to manipulate strings in Ansible, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        d2: "{{ _a.2 }}-{{ _a.1 }}-{{ _a.0 }}"
      vars:
        d1: 22-12-2021
        _a: "{{ d1.split('-') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  d2: '2021-12-22'
```

---

This is a nice one-liner (credit @Sijaan Hallak) which gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        d2: "{{ d1.split('-')[::-1]|join('-') }}"
      vars:
        d1: 22-12-2021
```

---

The next option is [Handling dates and times](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times) functions, e.g. create the date object

```yaml
      set_fact:
        d2: "{{ d1|to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y') }}"
      vars:
        d1: 22-12-2021
```

gives

```yaml
  d2: '2021-12-22 00:00:00'
```

and use *strftime* filter to format the string, e.g.

```yaml
      set_fact:
        d2: "{{ (d1|to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  d2: '2021-12-22'
```

Comment: Thank you! can you refer me to the documentation of this particular manipualtion?

Comment: Well, there is not much to refer to. You might want to search "Python split" and make your choice. The rest is simply [Intro to playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#about-playbooks) and [YAML](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-syntax).